# xrandr and panning gives random results

Tags: xorg, gnome, xrandr, touch-screen

I have a tablet pc with a hires display, which I'd like to use in landscape and portrait mode. I'm running Arch Linux (Kernel 4.10.11) and Gnome (Verion 3.22.2, Xorg 1.19.3). HiDPI can be enabled, but space is too limited on a 13" display. When HiDPI ist disabled, buttons are too small to touch. So I figured out, how to scale it somewhere inbetween:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 1.35x1.35 --fb 1944x3456 --panning 1944x3456
```

The FB and panning setting is needed to keep touch and pen input cover the whole display. Otherwise it would be limited to the scaled down area. Sometimes it works fine, but most of the time I get an error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  29 (RRSetPanning)
Serial number of failed request:  31
Current serial number in output stream:  31
```

I cannot figure out, when and why it throws this error. I do display rotation with just `xrandr -o 3` which always resets scaling to 2.0x2.0. Is there anything I've missed?